# ADO.Net + LINQ To SQL

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, ado.net

Can I use Both ADO.NET and LINQ To SQL in my Web Application developed in ASP.NET? Will it be ok at the time of deployment?

Actually i am developing web application where i want to use both some tasks in LINQ To SQL and some in ADO.Net.

Comment: Yes. Whether it's a good fit for your purposes is an entirely different matter.  Do you have a real question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can because LINQ is actually a TSQL in C#!